# Page loads and the item is not found

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I test some site. Just only try put some text into input field (near Site URL:). I use selenium. My code throw exception. Please, tell me why?

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
try
{
   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.w-global.com/index.php/tools-gadgets/online-sitemap-generator");
   IWebElement url_parse = driver.FindElement(By.Name("inputurl"));
   url_parse.SendKeys("http://test.com");
}
catch (Exception ee)
{
   String s = ee.ToString();
}
finally
{
   driver.Quit();
}
```

Error:

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {\"method\":\"name\",\"selector\":\"inputurl\"}\r\n   in OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs...

Comment: It's unable to locate the element, just like the error message says.  What else do you expect us to say?

Comment: How to do, that this code works?. After all, this element is 100% exists in the HTML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `IWebElement url_parse = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("inputurl"));` to 
`IWebElement url_parse = driver.FindElement(By.Name("inputurl"));`

**UPDATE**

Just noticed that the element is inside an iframe.

You need to switch to it before trying to find the element.

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("c-analyzer"); #and then
IWebElement url_parse = driver.FindElement(By.Name("inputurl"));
```

Comment: No.(By.Name("inputurl")) throw same error:OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {\"method\":\"name\",\"selector\":\"inputurl\"}\r\n   in OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse) in c:\\Projects\\WebDriver\\trunk\\dotnet\\src\\WebDriver\\Remote\\RemoteWebDriver.cs

Comment: made an edit. there was an iframe which u needed to switch to

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your `inputurl` from `IWebElement url_parse = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("inputurl"));` is wrong because there is no `inputurl` tag in in the html source.

What i can suggest ?

Try to use this selector instead yours

```
IWebElement url_parse = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.mfid-v3 input"));
```

i hope this is that input that you're looking for.

Plus, clear it before writing values in. Because your code will do that into the input:

```
http://http://test.com
```

So don't forget to `url_parse.clear();`

Tell me what's up =)

Comment: Your variant also does not work. IWebElement url_parse = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.mfid-v3 input")); Throw error: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {\"method\":\"css selector\",\"selector\":\"div.mfid-v3 input\"}\r\n

Comment: @JonMaximys Ok, did you try to use a `wait` ? Take a look [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)